# Perl Regex Conditional: named group inside embedded code

Tags: regex, perl

I'm a beginner in Perl, but I do know my way around regex.

Right now I'm stuck with a problem because I don't know the syntax I should use to do what I want in Perl.

In the RE I'm crafting, I need to name a group (composed of only one character) and then use it inside an embedded code to see if the character is equal to 'a', for example, and if it is the if-statement should be used to match what I want...

I thought the syntax would be something like this:

```
(echo base; echo case;) | perl -ne 'print if /^ *(?<char>[^*\/#" ])(?(?{<char> eq c})ase)/'
```

In this example, I want to match the string **case**, but it matches any character followed by **ase** (like **base**, in the example). That is really frustrating...

Can anyone with more experience in Perl show me the proper way to get this conditional right?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** In the example, I want to evaluate the group *char*. It should only match the lines that have *char* == 'c' and if that is true then 'ase' will be used as the IF-statement in the conditional, therefore matching case, but not base...

Comment: And I want to invent a knife that makes me a chicken curry sandwich. Perhaps you should just write regular code to do this job? Or provide a clearer description of what you need to do, and some test cases.

Comment: You can use a lookahead assertion to check for the presence of a particular character, e.g. `(?=c)`

Comment: It would be a look behind of some sort, but I wasn't able to make it work as I need to evaluate what the group <char> matched...

Comment: I'm using this concept in a much more complicated script. This is the simplest example I could come up to describe my problem... The script already works, but sometimes I need to check if I've matched the first character somewhat like in the example and in these cases the RE fails to behave as it should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the if-then-else statement I wanted to embed is shown bellow.

```
(echo qwert; echo base; echo case;) | perl -ne 'print if /^ *(?<char>[^*\/#" ])(?(?{$+{char} eq c})ase|_x_x_x_)/'
```

This command matches only the word **case** and leaves **qwert** and **base** out.

I also had to add an else statement that never matches and voilà, I was able to evaluate the content of the named group *char* as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `(?{ code })` to change the result of matching, as it's never false ([perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre)):

> This zero-width assertion evaluates any embedded Perl code. It always succeeds, and [...]

Comment: I don't want to change the result, I want to check if the group is equal to a given character using the conditional. I know (?(<char>)RE) works, but matching alone is not the condition, I want something like if(char=='c') ...

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to get the syntax right... In my example, how can I embed the if statement and where do $+{char} goes?

Comment: @dse: I don't understand what you want to do, so I can't help you more.

Comment: Actually, after some search and your advice, I ended up getting where I wanted with this: (echo qwert; echo base; echo case;) | perl -ne 'print if /^ *(?<char>[^*\/#" ])(?(?{$+{char} eq c})ase|_x_x_x_)/'

Comment: If you run the command, you will see that it only matches 'case' and leaves 'qwert' and 'base' out. I also had to add an else statement that is never true... Anyway, I don't know if I succeeded in explaining what I wanted, but anyway you advice helped a lot!